# Is there a way to pause a unit test without blocking the thread

Tags: java, unit-testing, playframework

I'm using play 1.2.4 and I'm trying to set up a unit test to test a job.
My job runs at every 2 second and changes the status of certain objects based on some conditions. This is what I use to do this.

```
@Every("2s")
public class GameScheduler extends Job {
    public void doJob(){
        //Fetch of object from db and status change based on conditions happens here
    }
}
```

Now in my unit test, I setup those conditions but I want the test to wait say 3 seconds before fetching one of the setup objects and do an assert Equals on its status to see if the job... well did it's job.

If I use

```
pause(3000);
```

or something like

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The test stops but the job also stops. It seems like the job and the test are on the same thread. Is there a way to pause the test without stopping the job? Something like the await() method in the controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to test the scheduler because it is supposed to work (since the framework is handling it). What you need is just test if the `doJob` method is doing its work. So, just write a test like this:

```
GameScheduler job = new GameScheduler();
job.doJob();

// assert whatever you want here
```

Comment: only problem could be the job running twice, once for the scheduler execution another for the direct invokation..

Comment: Thanks for the reality check  marcospereira.

Answer (score 0):

Though simply testing the job (without waiting for the scheduler to run it for you) would do the trick in most (read this as: probably all) situations, there are some in which it might be interesting to not have to trigger it manually.

For instance, you have a cluster of play apps that share a common configuration set. Change one config in one slave, all the others take note and do the same. Let's say the configuration is kept in memcached. One useful unit test is to manually change some setting using Cache.set, wait for the amount of time it takes for the configurationObserver job to run, then check that the internal config has been updated. This would be even more helpful if there would be a series of jobs updating the configuration, etc.

To do that, you must remember that play in DEV mode uses one thread (this helps debugging a lot, btw). You can simply add this line to your application.conf: %test.application.mode=prod and you'll have multiple threads.

Later edit: It appears that setting the mode to prod doesn't really help in this case. What does help is this: use some "await" magic.

```
@Test
public void myTest() { 
    final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    final Condition goAhead = lock.newCondition();
    /* Here goes everything you need to do before "pausing" */
    lock.lock();
    try {
        /**
         * Set whatever time limit you want/need 
         * You can also use notifiers like goAhead.signal(), from within another thread 
         */   
        goAhead.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        assertTrue(whateverINeedToTest);
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```